# Add classpath of third party jar in ant build file

Tags: ant, build, jar, classpath, jsoup

I want to use a third party jar file to be used in my ant project.
I guess that I should add something in build.xml file.
Actually I want to add Jsoup dependency in my build file.
I have read somethings after google search but i could not find out.
I already have tried

```
 <classloader loader="system">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="jsoup-1.6.2.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</classloader>
```

Can someone tell me how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. But later on I managed to solve the problem.
Since this is ant project. There is an ivy.xml so just adding ant dependency of jsoup in ivy.xml works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to add a jar to your javac classpath.

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="jsoup-1.6.2.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

You could also define the classpath outside the scope of javac (e.g. at top-level of your build file) and then refer to it by id in your javac task.